# Object.assign with boolean

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Whats the difference between

```
Object.assign({},obj1,obj2);
```

and

```
Object.assign(true,obj1,obj2);
```

I know what obj.assign does but whats the use of the latter one ? it returns a boolean type with obj1 and obj2 to merged into it.

PS: It was an interview question so would like to know whats the use case of this.

Comment: Do you have TypeError with the second way?

Comment: There is no *sane* use of the second one. I would hope never to see that in a codebase, ever.

Comment: No it works perfectly fine, no errors.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I agree, i was wondering the same but since they asked in the interview i thought it might be important.

Comment: It's not important, it's just silly trivia I think. Yes, Boolean objects can have properties assigned to them, but they really shouldn't.

Comment: `Object.assign` converts the first argument to an object if it isn't already (https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-object.assign). Boolean *objects* don't have any use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides boolean is supposed to be primitive type it has object-type wrapper that is... surprise Boolean.

In case of

```
Object.assign(true,{a: 1}, {b: 2})
```

there is such boxing(term from Java/C# worlds I really like) happens. And then `Object.assign` works over this object-type wrapper as it should. That's why result looks in console like

> Boolean {true, a: 1, b: 2}

Boolean's object like every other objects can be extended with custom keys/values. Output looks confusing but if you expand this in console you will see there is no actually "value of true without any key" - so it's just tricky output.

BTW exactly the same happens to strings when you tries to call some method on primitive value like

```
'12345'.split(/./)
```

It is converted into object with `String()` constructor and then call String's method.

And yes, I believe it should be never used in real life code.

Here is [spec says](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.assign):

> 1. Let to be ToObject(target).

So explicit converting primitive-to-object is very first step.

Answer (score 2):

As outlined above, primitives get "boxed", so the following:

```
 Object.assign(true, obj1, obj2)
```

is merely the same as:

```
 const bool = Object.assign(new Boolean(true), obj1, obj2)
```

now boolean objects are just regular objects, that return a boolean when `valueOf()` is called on them. That means you get some funny behaviour:

```
 bool === true // false
 bool == true // true
 +bool === 1 // true
```

You cannot even use that Boolean object inside conditions as all objects are truthy:

```
  if(Object.assign(false,{a: 1 }))
   alert("works");
```

So actually there is no difference between a regular object and a Boolean object, except that the latter adds some confusion and serves no purpose whatsoever.

Comment: just side note: `.valueOf()` returns primitive value back. So it's possible to unbox it for using it in `if()`.